# Doctrine Criteria - concatenating inside a Criteria

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, criteria

I'm trying to filter out claims from a collection where the claim date is earlier than 2016-01-01. Doctrine is not allowing me to do this sort of concatenation. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve the desired results?

```
public function getItems()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->gte('year' . '-' . 'month' . '-01', '2016-01-01));

    return $this->items ? $this->items->matching($criteria) : null;
}
```

The error I'm getting looks like this:

```
ORMException in ORMException.php line 101:
Unrecognized field: year-month-01
```

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query

Comment: @ShiraNai7 The docs don't seem to have any sort of Criteria to compare formatted dates.

Comment: Bind a `DateTime` object to a parameter and use that. No need to work with raw strings.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 This doesn't either seem to work. Can you post some code of how you would do this?

Comment: What are `year` and `month`? Entity fields?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 These are columns in my `Item` model. Usually I would use just one column as [illustrated in the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). In this case, the `year` and `month` are as two separate columns and I'm trying to concatenate them to compare the full date.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this is not DQL.